# Creating a List Lexer/Parser

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, lexer, tokenize

I need to create a lexer/parser which deals with input data of variable length and structure.

Say I have a list of reserved keywords:

```
keyWordList = ['command1', 'command2', 'command3']
```

and a user input string:

```
userInput = 'The quick brown command1 fox jumped over command2 the lazy dog command 3'
userInputList = userInput.split()
```

How would I go about writing this function:

```
INPUT:

tokenize(userInputList, keyWordList)

OUTPUT:
[['The', 'quick', 'brown'], 'command1', ['fox', 'jumped', 'over'], 'command 2', ['the', 'lazy', 'dog'], 'command3']
```

I've written a tokenizer that can identify keywords, but have been unable to figure out an efficent way to embed groups of non-keywords into lists that are a level deeper.

RE solutions are welcome, but I would really like to see the underlying algorithm as I am probably going to extend the application to lists of other objects and not just strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
keyWordList = ['command1', 'command2', 'command3']
userInput = 'The quick brown command1 fox jumped over command2 the lazy dog command3'
inputList = userInput.split()

def tokenize(userInputList, keyWordList):
    keywords = set(keyWordList)
    tokens, acc = [], []
    for e in userInputList:
        if e in keywords:
            tokens.append(acc)
            tokens.append(e)
            acc = []
        else:
            acc.append(e)
    if acc:
        tokens.append(acc)
    return tokens

tokenize(inputList, keyWordList)
> [['The', 'quick', 'brown'], 'command1', ['fox', 'jumped', 'over'], 'command2', ['the', 'lazy', 'dog'], 'command3']
```

Comment: I actually came up with something similar, but yours is a little more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
def tokenize(lst, keywords):
    cur = []
    for x in lst:
        if x in keywords:
            yield cur
            yield x
            cur = []
        else:
            cur.append(x)
```

This returns a generator, so wrap your call in one to `list`.

Answer (score 2):

That is easy to do with some regex:

```
>>> reg = r'(.+?)\s(%s)(?:\s|$)' % '|'.join(keyWordList)
>>> userInput = 'The quick brown command1 fox jumped over command2 the lazy dog command3'
>>> re.findall(reg, userInput)
[('The quick brown', 'command1'), ('fox jumped over', 'command2'), ('the lazy dog', 'command3')]
```

Now you just have to split the first element of each tuple.

For more than one level of deepness, regex may not be a good answer.

There are some nice parsers for you to choose on this page: http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

I think [Lepl](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) is a good one.

Comment: This will have problems whenever command1 is a substring of one of the other terms (e.g. "length" and "len".)

Comment: That's true. It's possible to add `\s` around the keyword list to solve that. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Or have a look at PyParsing. Quite a nice little lex parser combination